# How to group a list of Dictionaries into a sublists of Dictionaries by one of their key-values?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

How to group a list of Dictionaries into a sublists of Dictionaries by one of their key-values?

For example, I'd like to change this list of Dictionaries into sublists of Dictionaries

```
lst = [{'A':12,'B':32,'ID':333},{'Z':32,'C':43,'ID':111},{'D':43,'J':31,'ID':222},{'a':32,'b':31,'ID':222},{'D':43,'ID':333},{'a':89,'d':31,'ID':222},{'C':83,'ID':111}]


Desired_lst = [[{'A':12,'B':32,'ID':333},{'D':43,'ID':333}],[{'Z':32,'C':43,'ID':111},{'C':83,'ID':111}],[{'D':43,'J':31,'ID':222},{'a':32,'b':31,'ID':222},{'a':89,'d':31,'ID':222}]]
```

I've tried the following, which doesn't work, because I'm not sure how to apply groupby or sorted to a Dictionary.

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter


Desired_List = [list(grp) for key, grp in itertools.groupby(sorted(lst, key=operator.itemgetter(['ID'])),key=operator.itemgetter(['ID'))]
```

Comment: What, if anything, have you tried so far? Also, this seems to be grouping, rather than sorting.

Comment: Added what I tried, which I know works for list of lists, but I'm not sure how to apply it to a list of Dictionaries

Comment: The original list of Dictionaries are not sorted in any particular way. It's pretty random.

Comment: I mean how do you want them sorted?

Comment: and why would you need to store the ID field in every element of a sublist? to me it looks like a poorly designed data structure. you might want to consider having an object with the fileds `id` and `elemtents` that store everything you need.

Comment: @Chris and what happened when you ran that code? Errors? Unexpected outputs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue with your current code is how you're calling [`itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter). The arguments should be the keys to use to access the object, without any container. You're passing a list, which isn't a legal dictionary key. Try:

```
keyfunc = operator.itemgetter("ID")
Desired_List = [list(grp) for key, grp in itertools.groupby(sorted(lst, key=keyfunc),
                                                            key=keyfunc)]
```